# How to get variable from vendor file in webpack 4

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4

Are there any ways to access variable e.q. `Lobibox` from vendor file:

`./node_modules/lobibox/js/notifications.js`

in my own configuration file: `./assets/js/lobibox/config.js`?

Just for override Lobibox default settings.

**Here is my stack:**

> ./assets/js/lobibox/config.js:

```
$(function ()
{
    Lobibox.notify.DEFAULTS = $.extend({}, Lobibox.notify.DEFAULTS,
    {
        soundPath: '/temp/static/sound/notifications/',
        icon: false,
        sound: 'sound4',
        width: 320,
        pauseDelayOnHover: true,
        continueDelayOnInactiveTab: false
    });
});
```

> ./node_modules/lobibox/js/notifications.js:

```
var Lobibox = Lobibox || {};
(function () {

    // code ..

    Lobibox.notify = function (type, options) {

        // code ..

    };

    // code ...

}})();
```

> ./entryFile.js:

```
// Notifications

import './../node_modules/lobibox/js/notifications.js';
import './static/js/notification.js'
```

And now browser shows error 
`Uncaught ReferenceError: Lobibox is not defined`

Comment: You should search for a term 'overriding method from node module'  here is an example how to do that, not sure is it applicable 100% in your case but I think this can be good start point to search better for solution: https://www.tutorialkart.com/nodejs/override-function-of-a-node-js-module/

Comment: is it still undefined if you try window.Lobibox in notification.js ?

Comment: @MarianBan yes still undefined. Lobibox is not appended into window variable.

Comment: @Nezir, it's not usable, because `require()` returns empty object. Maybe I can load content of the vendor file, override and execute. But now I don't know if it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For loading legacy code you can use [script-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/script-loader).

1. Install script-loader: `npm install --save-dev script-loader`
2. Add new entry at the beginning of the module rules section in your webpack config file:

   ```
   {
      test: /lobibox\/js\/notifications/,
      loader: "script-loader"
   }
   ```

You should able to access Lobibox under `window.Lobibox`.

Comment: Perfect solution! It can be used without **window.** Lobibox, just `Lobibox`

Comment: In my case I use script-loader just like this:
`import 'script-loader!./../node_modules/lobibox/js/notifications.js';`